# Function name scoping in c

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, makefile

How does function name scoping work across multiple C files?

I'm porting a standard gnu toolchain project to iPhone OS, and using Xcode to do it.

The code builds through make, but not through xcode. when building through xcode, the linker complains that the same symbol (function) is defined in two objects. the code has two distinct source files that `#include` a common file between them. While... odd (to me at least), it seems to work for the standard toolchain. any ideas if this is something that's somehow handled differently through a standard makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it compiles without errors from the Makefile, but not from your XCode project, it is most likely because the compiler's options are being set differently in the two environments. Check the Makefile to see what options are passed to 'gcc'. In particular, it's possible that the duplicate definitions are conditionally-compiled with #ifdef, and you may need to add some preprocessor definitions to your XCode project's settings.

Answer (score 4):

All functions not marked static have global scope (they are dumped in a single namespace). Functions marked static are limited to the translation unit they are defined in.

You have a One Definition Rule violation.

One of your headers probably has a definition for a variable. E.g: in `common.h` you have

```
int foo = 42;
```

change it to:

```
extern int foo; // a declaration
```

and then create a `common.c` file where you put a definition:

```
int foo = 42;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, if I remember correctly, `static` function names are local to the source file in which they are defined, but all other function names exist in a global namespace.  So if you have `file1.c` with

```
void fn1() {}
static void fn2() {}
```

and `file2.c` with

```
void fn1() {}
static void fn2() {}
```

and you tried to compile them with something like

```
cc file1.c file2.c
```

then you would get a name conflict between the `fn1` in `file1.c` and the `fn1` in `file2.c`, but not between the two `fn2` functions (because they're static). (Of course, you'd get a bunch of other errors too because this program doesn't *do* anything, but those aren't relevant to scoping.)

Comment: i understand why the linker is complaining, i don't understand why it builds with the gnu toolchain.

file lm3_template.c defines method foo()

files foo.c and bar.c at some point does an #include lm3_template.c

linker complains about method foo()

ideas? is it a makefile trick?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the common header defines an inline function that is resulting in a duplicate symbol. If that is the case, prefix those functions with a `static inline`, or define them as `inline` with an `extern` declaration in another .c file.

Comment: inline was added to C99 -- not all compilers will support that. otherwise a vendor specific extension is required (on the command line).

Comment: True, but OP is compiling on iPhone SDK, which uses gcc that supports C99.